# Activity Cannot Be Resolved in Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, constructor

My app keeps crashing and I think it is because I do not have a default constructor. At least, that is what is referring to in the Android Manifest file. I try to add one but when I do add just a empty constructor, for example, "public LoaderImageView () {}" it will not recognize it and gives me errors. I will copy java and android code.

Please help, thank you.

Java:
    package com.example.imageviewloader;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

/**
* Created by Owner on 8/12/2017.
*/

public class LoaderImageView extends LinearLayout {

private static final int COMPLETE = 0;
private static final int FAILED = 1;


private Context mContext;
private Drawable mDrawable;
private ProgressBar mSpinner;
private ImageView mImage;


public LoaderImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrSet) {
    super(context, attrSet);
    final String url = attrSet.getAttributeValue(null, "image");
    if(url != null){
        instantiate(context, url);
    } else {
        instantiate(context, null);
    }
}

private void instantiate(final Context context, final String imageUrl) {
    mContext = context;

    mImage = new ImageView(mContext);
    mImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mSpinner = new ProgressBar(mContext);
    mSpinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);

    addView(mSpinner);
    addView(mImage);

    if(imageUrl != null){
        setImageDrawable(imageUrl);
    }
}

public void setImageDrawable(final String imageUrl) {
    mDrawable = null;
    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                mDrawable = getDrawableFromUrl(imageUrl);
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(COMPLETE);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private final Handler imageLoadedHandler = new Handler (new 
Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case COMPLETE:
                mImage.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
                mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case FAILED:
            default:
                // Could change image here to a 'failed' image
                // otherwise will just keep on spinning
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

private static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(final String url) throws 
IOException, MalformedURLException {
    return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new 
java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.imageviewloader">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoaderImageView">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Include your crash log in the post

Comment: You need a View for your application, and your Launcher java file is not extending any view (AppCompatActivity), so create an Activity extending AppCompatActivity and then run your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend Activity or AppCompatActivity or descendants for an activity. You cannot simply extend LinearLayout and assume it to be an activity.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Then what should be the answer?

Comment: Explaining him what to do with an Example, comment is for giving an idea so that the user can work on it, answer is for giving the whole idea of what he/she is missing and what to do to resolve the error.